# Data are gone after navigating to another tab and getting back to the previous one - php

Tags: php, session

When the admin logs in he could see all those who are registered including their personal details on the home tab, but when i navigate to the email tab and return back to the home tab all those data can't be seen. I am doubting it has something to do with sessions, can anyone please help me.

Here is the script when the admin logs in:

```
<?php 
   session_start();
   include_once 'navrequire.php'; 
      if(isset($_POST['usern']))
       {
           $usern = $_POST['usern'];
           $pass = $_POST['pass'];

           //session
           $_SESSION['usern']=$usern;

         //escaping
           $usern = stripcslashes($usern);
           $pass = stripcslashes($pass);
           $usern = mysql_real_escape_string($usern);
           $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($pass);


             $servername = "localhost";
             $username = "root";
             $password = "";
             $dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

 //Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='$usern' AND password='$pass'";

$validator = mysqli_query($conn, $query1)
 or die("Error establishing connection" .mysql_error());

$row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($validator);


 if($row1['username'] == $usern and $row1['password']== $pass){

echo '<div id="greet">Hello ' .$_SESSION['usern'].'</div> <br><br>';

$sql = "SELECT owner.firstname, owner.middlename, owner.lastname, ownerdetails.cpno, unitmembers.members, unitowner.unitNo, unitowner.squareMtrs
FROM unitowner INNER JOIN (unitmembers INNER JOIN (ownerlogindetails INNER JOIN (ownerdetails INNER JOIN owner ON ownerdetails.ownerDetId = owner.ownerId) ON ownerlogindetails.ownerLogDetId = owner.ownerId) ON unitmembers.unitMemId = owner.ownerId) ON unitowner.unitOwnId = owner.ownerId;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Middlename</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Unit Members</th>
<th>Unit No.</th>
<th>Unit Squaremeters</th>


<th>
</tr>";
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['middlename'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['members'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['unitNo'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['squareMtrs'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";

        } else {
            echo "0 results";
       }
}

else {
    header("Location: error.php");
}
$conn->close();


      }

 ?>
 </center>
```

Here is the mail page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Mail</title>
head>

<?php 
session_start();
include_once 'navrequire.php'; 
echo 'Hello ' .$_SESSION['usern'];
?>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

And the navrequire.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<title>headerInc</title>
<style>
        body {margin: 0;}

     ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}

/*ul li a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #111;}

ul li a.active {background-color: #4CAF50;}*/
li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
   position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
   min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
      ul li.right,
      ul li {float:none;}
}
</style>
<body>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="adminlog.php">Overview</a></li>
  <li><a href="mail.php">Mails</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">?</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="destroyer.php">Logout</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
    <br><br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seriously? You are expecting us to read *that* code? Please format it so that it is readable. Remove the empty lines, and insert line wraps where appropriate.

Comment: sorry @binarus i'm not really good on posting and questions.

Comment: We all were beginners at a certain point in time. But everybody posting a question here should at least take the time to re-read the question thoroughly after it has been posted and to correct obvious errors and unreadable formatting, especially when it comes to code. This is not a matter of knowledge, but a matter of attitude and respect towards the experts who you expect to spend their valuable time on your problem. Having said this, your question now (as per the time of this writing) is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Thank you @binarus

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at the mail page.

`<?php session_start();` 
must be at THE TOP of the page. No html before that.

Comment: The `if($row1['username'] == $usern and $row1['password']== $pass)` is the problem. Since the data in the table would show only if the username and password did match in the database, and probably that would only work after login. Thanks for your time @vladatr